# Vue2 Transition not working for new items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get a `transition-group` working so that my list items animate when deleted etc... I've got it working so far as when I "splice" an item from the list, it animates nicely. In this example, when I add a list it actually does animate, however you'll see in the console there's an error message:

`[Vue warn]: <transition-group> children must be keyed: <tr>`

In my real application, the list item doesn't get rendered, and there isn't an animation. If I remove the `transition-group` then the list item does successfully get added to the list

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/1481/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second argument in your `.push()` function.

So, change:

```
this.items.push(newItem, 1)
```

to

```
this.items.push(newItem)
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/eywraw8t/1587/

Comment: OK weird. That was a typo transposing it over to JSFiddle. That 1 isn't actually there in my original code.

Comment: Yeah, probably .. but it's working now so I guess that's what matters :)

Comment: It isn't actually. I still get the same error. Not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Well check the jsfiddle again https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/eywraw8t/1587/ I see no error in the console, so this means you might have slightly different code in your local. Make sure (as in the fiddle) you have `v-bind:key=''` for your loop, make sure the code is the same actually